# bat file enabledelayedexpansion won't expand in IF statement

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, delayedvariableexpansion

When I try delayed expansion of an environment variable **with a : clause** inside a .BAT file IF statement the line fails to parse/execute.  Using % signs instead of ! for the expansion works.  The identical delayed expansion works in other places, eg an ECHO statement.  For example:

```
@echo off& setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set t=abcd
echo !t:~0,2!
if %t:~0,2% == ab echo equal
if !t:~0,2! == ab echo equal
```

The **echo !t:~0,2!** correctly produces: ab

The **if %t:~0,2% == ab echo equal** correctly produces: equal

The **if !t:~0,2! == ab echo equal** issues the error:  **2! was unexpected at this time**

I don't understand why I can't use a delayed expansion **with a : clause** inside an IF statement.  Without the colon clause the delayed expansion inside the IF statement works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the delayed expansion itself, it's the comma inside.
That's because the batch parser expands the delayed expansion expression later than the percent expansion.
Therefore the `IF` parser *sees* the `!t:~0,2!` and takes the comma as a separator character.

You can simply avoid this by using quotes.
Or escaping the comma.

```
if "!t:~0,2!" == "ab" echo equal
if !t:~0^,2! == ab echo equal
```

You can read about the order of the different batch parser phases at [SO:How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/463115)

Comment: Appreciate it -- that solved my problem since I was working with strings in that case.  Still can be trouble with numeric IF comparisons, eg   set n=123& if  !n:~1,2! gtr 5  -- can't enclose the args in quotes because that forces a string comparison.  Using a set beforehand and removing the delayed expansion from the if statement fixes that.

Comment: @PaulH You can also escape the comma with a caret